# Об одном из значений слова "ещё"

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Известно, что одним из значений слова "ещё" является "до этого момента". Подразумевается ли при использовании слова "ещё", что действие/состояние скоро прекратится? Например, если я сказал: "Я ещё пользуюсь этой вещью", — можно ли из моих слов сделать вывод, что я планирую скоро перестать этой вещью пользоваться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, такой вывод сделать нельзя. Зачастую подразумевается обратное — действие будет продолжаться, и иногда настолько долго, насколько возможно. Пример: **Есть ещё порох в пороховницах**.

Но вот в отрицаниях (особенно в вопросительных предложениях и с усилением) действительно чаще предполагается ожидание скорого завершения действия. **Ты всё ещё не прочитал эту книгу?**

Для сравнения приведу такую пару предложений: **Он ещё болеет** (здесь не подразумевается скорое или ожидаемое выздоровление) и **Он всё ещё не выздоровел?** (а здесь спрашивающий предполагает, что выздоровление уже должно было наступить или вскорости наступит). Но эта разница определяется из контекста и статистики употребления выражений, а не по отдельным словам или грамматике предложения.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае подразумевается другое: ***вопреки ожиданиям*** (или предположениям собеседника), действие **продолжается** в настоящий момент. Предположений на будущее здесь не просматривается. Сам человек, вероятно, не рассчитывал, что вещь окажется долговечной или полезной, будучи старой. А возможно, он когда-то обещал отдать её собеседнику и купить себе вещь поновее. В данный момент он не спешит с этой вещью расстаться.

Answer (score 0):

"Я ещё пользуюсь этой вещью", — можно ли из моих слов сделать вывод, что я планирую скоро перестать этой вещью пользоваться?
Да. Например:
- Эта зубная щётка уже негодная!
1) - Не трогай, я ещё ей пользуюсь.
2) - Не трогай, я ей пользуюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать такой вывод. Будто подразумевается следующее:
*Я ещё [пока что] пользуюсь этой вещью.* || Но это ненадолго.

По мысли ощущается, что с вещью что-то не так — будто уже потрёпанная, старомодная или почти сломалась. В связи с этим очень вероятно, что это пользование скоро закончится.

И тут вдруг обнаружилось, что это значение **есть в словаре**:
б) Пока что.
*Он ещё совершенный ребёнок.

Малышу ещё два года.

Ты уже собрался? - Нет ещё.*

Примечание: При разных значениях слова "*ещё*" интонация кардинально отличается. Можно произнести так, что значение будет "*до сих пор*" или "*опять*".